# Elegant way of sharing URLs among projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let assume I have two web projects, one ASP.NET MVC and other ASP.NET WebAPI.

They are in different projects and runs in different hosts (www.whatever.com and data.whatever.com).

The MVC project needs to indicate the absolute URL of the endpoints in the WebApi project.

Which would be an elegant way of doing that? What I would like to avoid is to hardcode the URLs. Maybe something like share the route collection and use some trick to generate the full url giving the host name.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. While you could do some dynamic assembly loading to create a `UrlHelper` that uses the routes of another project, it's non-trivial and requires a hard-dependency between the projects, which kind of negates the purpose of separating them into different projects in the first place. For what it's worth, if your Web Api controllers reside in the same project as your MVC controllers (which is perfectly okay), then you could get the URLs for your Web Api endpoints like any other action.

Even if you did create a `UrlHelper` by dynamically loading in the other assembly, that *still* only nets you the path. The actual domain and application root of your Web Api project is impossible to get outside of the Web Api project itself.

While I completely identify with your desire to not hard code the Web Api endpoint URLs, you really don't have a choice here. You can somewhat mitigate this by wrapping your calls to the Web Api in some class, which at least keeps all the URLs in one place. You might also consider something like [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit), which will let you create one or more interfaces that represent your Web Api, allowing you to both abstract the URL and all the infrastructure for accessing it and working with the response in one fail swoop.

Answer (score 0):

In these scenarios, I would put these into AppSettings in your web.config files. While you still have to specify the URLs yourself, at least this allows you to specify a different URL depending on the deployment e.g. qa vs production vs local development machine.

Answer (score 0):

That is what configuration files are made for. In ASP.NET - it is first and foremost - Web.Config of your app instance. You can use AppSettings section and add URL by the key, or create your own config section if you like, but I think that in your case it is overkill.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebApiEndpointURL" value="http://localhost/WebApi/" />
```

In the app you can always access it from System.Configuration namespace.

```
Dim sURL as String = _
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebApiEndpointURL")
```